# Strip consecutive line breaks from contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my form, I'm copying the content of a contenteditable `div` into a hidden field, which gets sent to the db.

```
<%= form_for(@comment, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :content, class: 'js-NewCommentContentShadow' %>
    <div class="js-NewCommentContentField" contenteditable="true"></div>
<% end %>
```

I'm rendering that data in the view like this

```
<div><%=raw comment.content %></div>
```

The problem is, pressing the enter key outputs this line break

```
<div>
    <br>
</div>
```

You can add multiple line breaks consecutively, which is fine. But at some point, I'd like to strip all consecutive line breaks, so just a single line break is allowed before or after text.

That can happen as the contenteditable content is being copied to the shadow input, or as the form is submitted, or in the view somehow...I'm not fussy.

Here are some examples of how I want to affect the output:

This:

```
Some text
<div>
  <br>
</div>
Some more text
```

is fine and should be left as it is.

This:

```
Some text
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
Some more text
```

should be changed to

```
Some text
<div>
  <br>
</div>
Some more text
```

This:

```
Some text
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
```

should be changed to:

```
Some text
```

Comment: Have you tried using `gsub`? For example: `comment.content.gsub("<br>", "")`.

Comment: That is removing ALL line breaks. I want line breaks when the return key is pressed. But I only want to allow one consecutive line break.

Comment: I've tried `comment.content.gsub("<div><br></div><div><br></div>", "<div><br></div>")` but it doesn't work. It wouldn't work anyway because I need to account for an infinite number of these strings. Is it possible with gsub?

Comment: What is the exact content of `comment.content`?

Comment: I don't know, it's a user-generated comment. It can consist of text and any number of `<div><br></div>` instances.

Comment: I mean, an example :) Micael's answer should work, but maybe you are getting a different text. Try using pry, byebug or simply `puts` the conent in console to see an example.

Comment: Oh, sorry :) Here is one example `Some text<div>Some more text</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div>`. Here is another `Some text<div><br></div><div>Some text</div>`. The second example is fine. The first example has a load of unwanted line breaks at the end.

Comment: There's more than meets the eye within that string; you need to account for some _special characters_. Check my answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the string in `comment.content` contains non-printable characters (specifically *unicode zero width joiner* characters), so the string `<div><br></div>` is not always a match because of this *invisible* characters.

To get around this you first need to remove those characters from the string and then remove the extra `<div><br></div>` occurrences.

One way to do it is using `gsub` along with `\p{Cf}` regex<sup>1</sup> and the use `gsub` again to replace the extra `<div><br></div>`, like this:

```
comment.content.gsub(/\p{Cf}/, "").gsub(/(<div><br><\/div>)+/, "<div><br></div>")
#=> "Some text<div>Some more text</div><div><br></div>. Here is another Some text<div><br></div><div>Some text</div>"
```

To completely remove all `<div><br></div>` occurrences at the end of the string (example 3), you could add another gsub that removes that substring from the end of the string, for example:

```
comment.content.gsub(/\p{Cf}/, "")
       .gsub(/(<div><br><\/div>)+/, "<div><br></div>")
       .gsub(/(<div><br><\/div>)+$/, "")
```

The added `$` in the regexp stand for *end of string*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *`\p{Cf}` stands for* 'Other: Format' *in* Unicode character's General Category. *Refer to [Regexp class documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) for more information.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks Gerry, super helpful! The code you provided fixes most things, but it replaces consecutive line breaks with a single line break, I want to replace consecutive line breaks with nothing.

Comment: Just change `gsub(/(<div><br><\/div>)+/, "<div><br></div>")` to `gsub(/(<div><br><\/div>)+/, "")`.

Comment: I tried that but that just removes all line breaks. I want to leave singular line breaks, but remove all line breaks when they're followed by nothing, or when they're followed by another line break. When they're followed by text, I want to retain them. Thanks though, I might find the answer if I play with it for a while.

Comment: @colmtuite Hmm, can you provide the desired output for the sample string you provided?

Comment: I updated the question with the desired output for a number of possible scenarios. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: @colmtuite Check updated answer, it covers all provided scenarios. I hope it helps!

Comment: Yep, that fixed everything. Thanks so much for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
"<div><br><br></div><br><br><br><div><br></div><br>".gsub(/(<br>){2,}/, '<br>')
```

outputs

```
=> "<div><br></div><br><div><br></div><br>"
```

basically, match any 2 or more occurrences - `{2,}` - of group `()`, `<br>`, and substitute for `<br>`. So pick all where `<br>` appears repeated  (more than once) and substitute for a single `<br>`. 
In your actual case you might need to add tolerance to `white space`, `line breaks`, etc.

Comment: Do you mean `<%=raw comment.content.gsub(/(<br>){2,}/, '<br>') %>`? I've tried that but it's not having any effect. I don't understand why you have `=>` in your code, or where I'm supposed to put that in my view?

Comment: There's 2 things there, there's the regex part, enclosed by `/ /`, this is usable in different places, you can do it in JS as your user types, wtv. The remaining is ruby, `gsub(/pattern/, 'substitution')` . To use `gsub` you'll have to use it on render or after the form is submitted. Like I said, you might have to include line breaks and white space, wtv. You need to see what your `raw` actually outputs and adapt it.

Comment: I have tried `<%=raw comment.content.gsub(/(<br>){2,}/, '<br>') %>` and it appears to have zero effect on the output. Am I using it incorrectly? Or do I need to tweak the syntax?

Comment: you need to see what is the output of `comment.content`, a real example where it's not working so that you can account for the pattern differences

Comment: I've been trying various combinations but the problem right now is, I'm trying the code you suggested but it's not have any affect at all on the output. This is the exact string I'm trying to remove `<div><br></div>`. When that string occurs more than one time consecutively, I want to replace it with "". Can you show me how to achieve that please?

Comment: @colmtuite no sweet pie I can't