# IE11 Intl.DateTimeFormat output won't match regex

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime, internet-explorer-11

This is both a question and an answer so that the next time I encounter this bug and Google for an answer, I'll find it here.

The output of

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',    
})
```

Is like `3/7/2020 6:43:00 AM` in IE11. It *looks* like this regex (please do not judge my regex skills):

```
/:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/g
```

Should match the `:43:00` portion, and it does in other browsers. But it does not in IE11. What gives?

Comment: @RobG This seems related but not a duplicate. The other q/a you linked to is helpful, but not for Javascript. I looked for a similar regex entity to `\p{Cf}` for javascript implementations but did not find one.

Comment: Duplicate of [*IE's toLocaleString has strange characters in results*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574963/ies-tolocalestring-has-strange-characters-in-results). Other useful questions: [*ToLocaleDateString() changes in IE11*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11), [*Strip consecutive line breaks from contenteditable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269759/strip-consecutive-line-breaks-from-contenteditable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from IE11 contains invisible left-to-right markers (`\u200E`) causing the regex to not match.

My solution was to remove these first, before trying to do anything with the string:

```
myDateTimeStr.replace(/\u200E/g, '')
```

I got the clue from this [issue report on react-intl](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/issues/201).